# how do I make twitter bootstrap page look the same on different screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have started using twitter boostrap and could not find how to make web site looks the same on different screens sizes

first, the top nav bar collapse and become a menu bar on small screens then the contents start to wrap and fall down on small screens too,

I am pretty sure there is some option or something to prevent this behavior, searching internet and documents, I could not find anything, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the **bootstrap-responsive.css**. If you are loading from a CDN, make sure that you are using a non-combined version of the CSS.

For example, here is the non-responsive version from BootstrapCDN:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

You can find more info on responsive design in Bootstrap in the [Responsive Design section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) of the official Bootstrap documentation.